# HTML5 File text disappears from textarea almost immediately when I OK alert

Tags: html, file, textarea

The HTML below seems to successfully reads a text file from client PC and display it in textarea.  However it is immediately blanked in Firefox and fails completely in Chrome.  No idea what happens in IE as I dont have a copy.

First browse(Firefox) or Choose(Chrome);  Then click "Load CAD Data"

```
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8;" />
    <title>miCAD 0.00 </title>

    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    "use strict";
    function loadCadFile(){
var fileName=document.getElementById('fileName').files[0];
var fileReader=new FileReader();
fileReader.onload=function(e){
    var textFromCadFile=e.target.result;
    var el=document.getElementById('CADdata');
    el.style.display='block';
    el.innerHTML=textFromCadFile;
    };
fileReader.onerror=function(e){
    alert('read error');};
fileReader.readAsText(fileName,"UTF-8");
    alert('xxx');
}
//--></script>

</head><body>
<form name="f" action="" method="post" >
<p>CAD file selector</p>
<table class="tc">
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="file" id="fileName" /></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td class="right">
<button onclick="loadCadFile(); alert('yyy');">Load CAD data</button></td></tr>
</table>
<textarea id="CADdata" width="90%" rows="10"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="40000" />
<input type="submit" value="just in case">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Example code is at "mips-erp.com/CAD/test.html as the above is my best attempt at pasting and then aligning the code

Comment: Please don't overwrite questions with answers, if you have the answer, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `innerHTML` to set the content of a text area you use `value`

```
el.value=textFromCadFile;
```

Comment: where to replace this

Answer (score 0):

I recoded it.  Working code follows:

```
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8;" />
    <title>miCAD 0.00 </title>

    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    "use strict";
     function loadCadFile(fileData){
        var fileReader=new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload=function(e){
            document.getElementById('CADdata').value=e.target.result;
            };
        fileReader.readAsText(fileData.files[0]);
        }
    //--></script>

    </head><body>
    <form name="f" action="" method="post" >
    <p>CAD file selector</p>
    <table class="tc">
    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="file" id="fileName" onchange="loadCadFile(this)" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    <textarea id="CADdata" width="90%" rows="10"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="40000" />
    </form>
    </body></html>
```